# Multiple Spring Boot project use same ValidationMessages.properites file

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am working on multiple Spring Boot projects. However, I want to use same `ValidationMessages.properties` file for all projects.

I have similar project structure can be seen below:

```
PROJECTS
> project-A
 > src
  > main
   > java
    > com
    > resources
     > ValidationMessages.properties
>project-B
 > src
  > main
   > java
    > come
    > resources
     > application.properties
```

So, in project B, I want to use `ValidationMessages.properties` file that is located in project-A. Also, I have project-C, project-D.. so on.

Is there any way to use one `ValidationMessages.properties` file from different Spring Boot projects.

I have tried to specify by modifying `application.properties` file in project-B with `classpath_ValidationMessages=classpath:/ValidationMessages` line. Yet, it didn't work. I couldn't find the right way.

Comment: Hi & welcome! The use case is no problem (using (& overriding) classpath resources of "dependencies" ..as long you know their location/fqn) One confusion is: `src/main/java/resources` is rather uncommon and doesn't match `classpath:/...` (it matches `classpath:/resources/...`,) alternatively more convenient: `src/main/resources/` ..which results (with maven based build tools) in `classpath:/`

Comment: So best: 1. Introduce "maven artifact" (group:artifact:version), containing/publishing `src/main/resources/ValidationMessages.properties` (+i18n!?) 2. Introduce a (compile/runtime) dependency on 1. 3. Refer (1. from 2.) as `classpath:/ValidationMessages.properties`.